# Fullscreen tableviewheader, show navigationbar on scroll

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, fullscreen, navigationbar

I'd to create an interface similar to the following url: https://dribbble.com/shots/3818990-Days-for-iPhone-X

I'm not that experienced with UI design so I'm not sure where to start.

I'd like to create the detail view. I think I need to create a tableview header that is the same size as my device resolution. On scroll I need to start showing the navigationbar. Is this the best solution? How do I do this?

Comment: Why don't you do this in tableview cell?

Comment: @salmancs43, that is also an option but Im not sure how to handle the part with the navigationbar